# Powershell script - break loop

Tags: windows, powershell

Giving this little script in powershell:

```sh
$index = 1
$file = "C:\Users\myfile"

while ($index -le 100000)
{
    $init_size = Write-Host((Get-Item $file).length/1KB)
    <here is my command which populates $file>
    $final_size = Write-Host((Get-Item $file).length/1KB)
    $index ++
    sleep 5
    If ($final_size -eq $init_size) {break}
}
```

I don't understand why it breaks even if the init_size is different from the final_size.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Write-Host` writes directly to the screen buffer and doesn't output anything, so the value of both `$init_size` and `$final_size` are effectively `$null` when you reach the `if` statement.

Do `Write-Host $variable` *after* assigning to `$variable` and it'll work:

```bsh
$index = 1
$file = "C:\Users\myfile"

while ($index -le 100000) {
    $init_size = (Get-Item $file).Length / 1KB
    Write-Host $init_size

    <here is my command which populates $file>

    $final_size = (Get-Item $file).Length / 1KB
    Write-Host $final_size

    $index++

    sleep 5

    If ($final_size -eq $init_size) { break }

}
```

Calling `Write-Host` on the results of the assignment expression itself would work too:

```
Write-Host ($init_size = (Get-Item $file).Length / 1KB)
```